# Change image when mouse over link (hover) and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does anybody know how to make an animation like this
http://www.hariripontarini.com/projects/corporate

Thanks!
Mars

Comment: Yes I do, however I am not going to do it for you, please demonstrate what you have tried and where it is perhaps not working.  If you don't know where to start I suggest you can perhaps read about jQuery first and it's selectors and CSS manipulation,

Comment: Hi Mars, people on earth, first try by themselves :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selectors, id/classes, and then with [`mouseenter()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) on links, change the css property `opacity` for the specific image element:

```
$("#first").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $("#1").css('opacity', '0.3');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $("#1").css('opacity', '');
    }
});
```

And vice versa (to change opacity on links when hovering over an image) ..

```
$("#1").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $("#first").css('opacity', '0.3');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $("#first").css('opacity', '');
    }
});
```

**[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/100k6gbp/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
.theClassThatTargetsYourImageContainer:hover {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

However, in order to select the right item in the list you can't really use CSS, but you can listen to the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events with jQuery and make the magic happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.imageClass').hover(function() {
     $(this).fadeOut();
}, function() {
     $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

or

```
$('.imageClass').hover(function() {
     $(this).css("opacity", .5);
}, function() {
     $(this).css("opacity", 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want.

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
   <img class="thumbnail thumb-200 " alt="02. McKinsey &amp; Co. Jakarta" src="http://www.hariripontarini.com/hpa/wp-content/uploads/mcj_01-200x200.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.test :hover{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaganGami/94wavmak/)**

Comment: Thanks, but the tricky thing for me is the interaction with the text links and vice versa. Mouse over text link - image changes, mouse over image, text link changes.